# Background photo not displaying with GraphQL in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm learning GraphQL and I tried to make a background photo at the Hero section. It does not work and I tried a lot to fix it. The code I used is below.
Some modules are imported for other parts of the file.
There is no error while running the code. The background photo just does not display.
I also attached code from gatsby-config.js.

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { StaticImage, GatsbyImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

const Hero = ({myBackground}) => {
    return (
        <HeroContainer>
            <HeroBg>
                {myBackground.allFile.edges.map(({node}) => (
                    <p key={node.id}>
                        {node.base}
                    </p>
                ))}
            </HeroBg>
        </HeroContainer>
        
export default Hero;

export const myBackground = graphql`
        query MyQuery {
            allFile {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    base
                    relativePath
                    relativeDirectory
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData 
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
`    

const HeroContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: -104px -8px -10px -8px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: lightgreen;
`
const HeroBg = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
`
```

The gatsby-config.js file below:

```js
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,

    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/data/`,
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your GraphQL query works as expected and fetches the proper data, your issue is on props destructuring and data loop.

Your component should look like:

```
const Hero = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <HeroContainer>
            <HeroBg>
                {data.allFile.edges.map(({node}) => {
                   console.log(node);
                   return <p key={node.id}>
                        {node.base}
                    </p>
                })}
            </HeroBg>
        </HeroContainer>
        
export default Hero;

export const myBackground = graphql`
        query MyQuery {
            allFile {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    base
                    relativePath
                    relativeDirectory
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData 
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
`
```

Since you are using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/), your approach will only work if `Hero` is a top-level component (a page inside `src/pages`). In that case, your fetched data will be always inside `props.data.queryOuterNode`, where `queryOuterNode` stands for `allFile` in this case.

If you are using an isolated component to fetch the data as it seems, you will be forced to use a [`useStaticQuery` hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) to fetch data in a non-top-level component. In this case, your component should look like:

```
const Hero = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query MyQuery {
            allFile {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    base
                    relativePath
                    relativeDirectory
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData 
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
  `)
    return (
        <HeroContainer>
            <HeroBg>
                {data.allFile.edges.map(({node}) => {
                   console.log(node);
                   return <p key={node.id}>
                        {node.base}
                    </p>
                })}
            </HeroBg>
        </HeroContainer>
        
export default Hero;
```

In this case, `Hero` is not receiving any `data` `props` and the data is fetched in the runtime, as the code requests it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both. With the second solution which seemed better to me I received this error below:

Error in function Hero in ./src/components/Hero.js:29

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'edges')

./src/components/Hero.js:29

```js
  27 |         <HeroContainer>
  28 |             <HeroBg>
> 29 |                 {data.allFile.edges.map(({node}) => {
     |                              ^
  30 |                     return 
  31 |                     <p key={node.id}>
  32 |                         {node.base}
```

Okay, I found the solution. It does not use GraphQL in fact, but I achieved what I wanted to that is a background image in the Hero section. The code is below:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'


const Hero = () => {
    return (
        <HeroContainer>
            <HeroBg>
                <StaticImage src="../images/Image.jpeg" />
            </HeroBg>
        </HeroContainer>
```